# Minted fancyverb error in beamer

Tags: beamer, minted, fancyvrb

I'm using minted for code higlight in a beamer presentation, and I'm getting an error:

`FancyVerb Error:. ^^I^^I^^I\end{minted}^^I`

```
\documentclass[]{beamer}
\usepackage{minted}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[fragile]{Title}

\begin{minted}{bash}
Some text
\end{minted}    

\end{frame}
\end{document}
```

I don't see the issue with such a simple use case.

Comment: The code as shown in the question compiles without errors for me. Can you show your .log file so we can see which engine you use, if you have shell-escape enabled and which versions of all the packages you have? Can you also double check that your code really looks like this? Sometimes a space or tab can already make the difference.

Comment: The whole issue was just an extra tab after the `\end{minted}`. Sometimes LaTeX quirks are too annoying.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it's solved according to the OPs own comment and answer: just a simple extra character confusing the tool ...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the reason: `FancyVerb Error:. ^^I^^I^^I\end{minted}^^I`

This `^^I` at the end is a tab, and according to [this](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/365528/stuff-following-minted-environment-causes-error), minted and other verbatim environments do not like any non space character after their `\end{}`. Removing the tab fixes the issue.